# How to add row to specific rank, DataViewGrid, C#

Tags: c#, date

I have `DataViewGrid` with three columns.

```
| ID | NAME | DATE |
```

DATE is type of `DateTime`.

I want to add rows so that they are ordered by date.
How?

Example:

```
1 JACOB 27.5.2015 23:15.10
6 PETER 27.5.2015 23.16.10
9 PETER 27.5.2015 23.16.41
```

Data are addet by method:

```
public void add(int id, String name, DateTime dateTime)
```

Comment: Are you adding these rows all at once or one at a time? Where are you adding them from (Textboxes, DataTable, List<T>, etc.)?

Comment: Hi guys i edited post. Look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the default sort method of the DataGridView.
First, you need to make sure that all cells in this row have the same ValueType (set the ValueType through e.g. `dataGridView1[0,2].ValueType=typeof(DateTime);)`

Then you need to make the Column "sortable", by setting
`dataGridView.Columns[2].SortMode=DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;`

And through following code you can sort your rows by column ascending
`dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Ascending);`